# How to access mysql from ubuntu in vmware

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vmware

I have MySQL installed in a Windows pc and have Ubuntu installed in VMWARE.
When I am trying to access MySQL through a hibernate application in Ubuntu I am getting the following error : **Host 'HOSTNAME' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server**
. What configuration changes do I need to make to access MySQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to GRANT access to your remote user/host.  See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html) or this [article](http://www.31bit.com/technology/86-mysql-database/302-how-to-grant-remote-access-to-a-mysql-database).
The GRANT syntax is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/grant.html).
HTH.

Comment: so , if my schema is 'test', user is 'root' , password is 'pass' , then the command should be and remote ip is x.x.x.x then the command should be GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* to 'root'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' ?

Comment: I suppose that by schema you mean database (i.e the name that appears in `show databases;`)? I would try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* to root@'x.y.z.w' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';`

Comment: thanks a lot . Yes , by schema I meant database as they are used interchangeably in MySQL